# In MonoDevelop, should the "[project]/bin" directory be put under version control?

Tags: version-control, monodevelop

I have my VCS set up to ignore "[project]/bin". Is this directory essential to restore a project, or can it safely be ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "bin" directory can be safely ignored. MonoDevelop will create it when building the project.

Answer (score 1):

If MonoDevelop recreates the bin directory when you delete it, then this is simply a matter of taste, otherwise you have to leave it in. (Rails happens to give up if you delete its logs).

Putting empty directories under version control can make the build process more readily apparent to those who glance at the repository, but it can also clutter and distract if you'd rather see only the essentials.